# Rally: Start process/program when saving changes?

Tags: web-services, ipc, dynamics-crm, rally

I've been tasked with re-working some code to integrate CRM and Rally.

Currently, we have a piece of code that sits on a server and every so often hits the Rally REST service to pull down items that have changed and shunt them over to CRM. CRM can be set up to call a piece of code whenever specific things happen (new item, changes, etc) so there is no intermediate code or delay involved.

Can Rally be set up to do the same thing?

Thank you very much,

Rex

Comment: Which crm are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry, it's Microsoft Dynamics.

Answer (score 0):

Rally doesn't have any scheduler/triggering mechanism such that you could set it up to automatically poll in response to certain events. The most workable option would likely be to use one of Rally's [REST toolkits](https://developer.help.rallydev.com/rest-apis) to develop a scheduled poller that runs on an external system.